# BASH script usage/help convention

Tags: bash

What is the convention for showing the usage of a bash script ?
Below is the help output for my script

```
Usage: my_script [options] [PORT]

Options:
    --help      print help and exit
    --version   print version and exit
```

Am i right in thinking that [ ] means optional

How do I signify an optional argument and a mandatory argument ?

Comment: Why should it be bash-specific? Check the help message returned by various GNU utils.

Comment: I think mandatory ones don't go in brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of commandline tools that i use frequently is "find" and "grep". While find runs happy without any parameters (all parameters are optional) grep needs at least a pattern. In case grep is invoked with no paramters at all it prints usage information like follows

```
Aufruf: grep [OPTION]... MUSTER [DATEI]...
"grep --help" liefert weitere Informationen.
```

Where MUSTER is the german word for pattern.